# Is it OK to get an alert from Gmail while browsing through Tor Browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, google, middle

I've just receive an e-mail in my Gmail saying

> Google 2-Step Verification blocked a sign in attempt to your account.

It also states that

> If it wasn’t you, then someone else knows your password, and you
>   should secure your account now.

There is also some information of the attempt:

> Windows 
>   Wednesday, May 16, 2018 5:50 PM (France Time)
>   Paris, France
>   Firefox

I had logged in in my Gmail account around that time through Tor Browser. Immediately, I checked the circuit I was using and there was a node from France, but it was a **middle node**.

Is it OK to get that alert?
Is it possible the way Tor connects a user to his Google account triggers those kind of alerts?
Should I be worried about a middle node turning rogue?

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible for the middle to know you were visiting GMail. It didn't go rouge.

It's likely Google uses a different GeoIP database than Tor Browser. When Google saw an exit that's allegedly in France, Tor Browser might be thinking the exit is allegedly in Germany. Just as an example.

It was you that triggered the alert because you're coming from the spooky scary terrible Tor network. There's nothing to worry about.

Comment: It's impossible as long as there are no flaws in Tor network. Also, why Google said it had blocked a login attempt if I was logged in successfully?